# Обработчики в цикле

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, с циклом. Дело в том, что на все обработчики цикл вешает в value = опрос

```
var granul = {
    photo_icon: document.getElementById('photo_icon1'),
    video_icon: document.getElementById('video_icon1'),
    quest_icon: document.getElementById('quest_icon1')
}

for (prop in granul) {
    var value
    if (granul[prop] == granul.photo_icon) {
        value = 'фото'
    } else if (granul[prop] == granul.video_icon) {
        value = 'видео'
    } else if (granul[prop] == granul.quest_icon) {
        value = 'опрос'
    } else {
        value = х
    }
    granul[prop].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        this.style.width = '40px'
        this.innerHTML = value
    }, false)
}
```

Comment: что содержит в себе granul?

Comment: [Дежавю](http://hashcode.ru/questions/167570/javascript-проблема-с-обработчиками-в-цикле)

Comment: @lampa granul содержит id элементов

Comment: @Spectre, а я так и думал) что тут это же фигня.  Просто прошлый раз было не много другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Просто прошлый раз было не много другое

`j` вместо `value`...это в корне меняет ситуацию

а вы не думали, что можно упростить цикл?

```
var granul = {
    photo_icon: {
        el: document.getElementById('photo_icon1'),
        value: 'фото'
    }, 
    video_icon: {
        el: ...,
        value: 'видео'
    },
    quest_icon: {
        el: ...,
        value: 'опрос'
    }
}
```

Comment: @Spectre
  var granul = {
   photo_icon: {
    el: document.getElementById('photo_icon1'),
    value: 'фото'
    }, 
   video_icon: {
    el: document.getElementById('video_icon1'),
    value: 'видео'
 
   quest_icon: {
    el: document.getElementById('quest_icon1'),
    value: 'опрос'
    } 
  }
  for( prop in granul){
   granul[prop].el.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
     this.innerHTML = granul[prop].value
   },false)
   }

Answer (score 1):

Если упрощать, тогда так

```
var granul = [{
     el: document.getElementById('photo_icon1'),
     val: 'фото'
}, {
     el: document.getElementById('video_icon1'),
     val: 'видео'
}, {
     el: document.getElementById('quest_icon1'),
     val: 'опрос'
}];

granul.forEach(function(item){
    item.el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      this.style.width = '40px';
      this.innerHTML = item.val;
    }, false);
});
```

​

Comment: @vonica а без jQuery ?

Comment: тут без jquery

Comment: @vonica  подожди а forEach ?

Comment: это `Array.prototype.forEach` к jQuery не имеет отношения

Comment: я об этом и написал, в jquery есть $.each

Comment: Интересно, а можно ли в Вашем коде заменить this на item.el ? Т.е. вместо this.style.width = '40px'; вот так: item.el.style.width = '40px'; и т.д.